# Help me identify rough pipe please!

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, drain, plumbing-fixture, rough-in

Can you help me identify pipe number 1?   I have a picture of the inside and not sure what it is and if it needs access.  I think I have the other pipes correct...

1. ?????????
2. Vanity Drain
3. Toliet Drain
4. Tub Drain

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do your building plans show? Should be marked and labelled - or don't any plans exist?

Comment: google what is written on the part ... try `canplas 3283` to start

Comment: It's there to provide access to the backwater valve. It can be cut flush to the floor, but it needs to remain accessible. If there could be a layer of flooring shifting the floor's elevation, it would be wise to wait on chopping it down until the floor is definitely at its final elevation.

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google search for `canplas 3283` reveals that it is a `backwater valve`.

It prevents sewer backup.

The pipe is just an access tube.

https://canplas.com/plumbing/product_category/backwater-valves/